# Как закрыть меню при нажатии на ссылку в меню?

Tags: javascript, меню

Помогите решить проблему. Как закрыть меню, при нажатии на ссылку в меню?
Код:

```
 $('.menu-sandwich').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {

        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().removeClass('menu-visible');
        $('.mobile-menu-background').removeClass('active');
        $('.header__logo').show();

        $('.main-menu li').removeClass('bounceInUp');
        $('.main-menu').addClass('animated fadeOutUp');

    } else {

        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('menu-visible');
        $('.mobile-menu-background').addClass('active');
        $('.header__logo').hide();

        $('.main-menu').removeClass('animated fadeOutUp');
        $('.main-menu li').addClass('animated bounceInUp');

    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте код вроде этого:

```
   // По клику на ссылку меню
   $('.main-menu li a').on('click', function () {
      // Здесь тоже самое что в вашем коде, можно объединить в отдельную функцию чтобы не дублировать код
      $('.menu-sandwich').removeClass('active');
      $('.menu-sandwich').parent().removeClass('menu-visible');
      $('.mobile-menu-background').removeClass('active');
      $('.header__logo').show();
      $('.main-menu li').removeClass('bounceInUp');
      $('.main-menu').addClass('animated fadeOutUp');
    });
```